# How can I set a background color via hsla with jquery.css()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can't seem to get jQuery.css() to accept an hsla() value.  Is it not an acceptable format to pass a color value in? This is what I have tried:

```
// the below variable outputs a variable value with the following format
// hsla(131, 10%, 100%, 1.0)
var finalcolor = "hsla(" +colx +", " +coly +"%, " +"100%, " +"1.0)";

$('#target-div').css('background', finalcolor);
```

Comment: did yo try to change background to background-color?

Comment: I've tried both variations.  No dice...

Comment: You realise you could've right-clicked the element and selected 'inspect element' which would've shown you the changed `background-color`? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JrAgM/).

Comment: what browser and version did you try it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does work, but your color is just white!

Check resulting style in firebug / chrome debugger, and check the HSL 2 RGB converter.
http://serennu.com/colour/hsltorgb.php

Comment: I've passed hard-coded variables that aren't white with no luck.  Yet, when I pass a hex value it does.

Scratch that, you're right.  What a silly mistake.  
Thank You!!!

Comment: Don't vary colx and coly but also the "100%" value, which changes the "Lightness". Check this example with a 94% value: http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/Z3Wbr/